# difference between first('a') and find('a:eq(0)')

Tags: jquery

Can someone elaborate it what is the exact difference between first('a') and find('a:eq(0)') in my example: why find('a:eq(0)')  works but first('a')  not!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/VZcnE/2/)

```
    $(this).closest('.menu-item').first('a').addClass('active'); 
    $(this).closest('.menu-item').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

Thanks

Comment: `.first()` takes no arguments.

Comment: they are completely different... also [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) does not take an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.first()` takes no arguments, your jQuery isn't valid.

These are equivalent:

```
$(this).closest('.menu-item').find('a').first().addClass('active'); 
$(this).closest('.menu-item').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VZcnE/4/)**

Answer (score 3):

From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/first/)** of `.first()`:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.

So `.first()` does not take any argument, it only select the first match element from your selector. You need to use:

```
$(this).closest('.menu-item').find('a').first().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

`first` doesn't take any parameters and it is a `jQuery` function, it works within a set of matched elements, that's why it doesn't work. Whereas `:eq(n)` is a css pseudo class. That's the main difference

Answer (score 0):

As per the jQuery documentation for first ([here](http://api.jquery.com/first/)), first *Reduces the set of matched elements to the first in the set.*, and a big note, it does not take a selector i.e. first('a') is not valid. Thinking of it in your context it would be reducing the collection of `.menu-item` to the first one, not finding the first `a` tag, but closest only finds one anyway so your top line of code closest and first are doing the same thing